# Yii2/PHP: Check connection to MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, yii2

When starting my Yii2/PHP application, how can I check if / wait until the database is up?

Currently with MySQL I use:

```
$time = time();
$ok = false;
do {
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    if ($pdo->query("SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA")) 
        $ok=true;
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    sleep(1);
  }
} while (!$ok && time()<$time+30);
```

Now I want make my application running with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

But `SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` does not work in PostgreSQL.

Is there a SQL-statement (using PDO database connectivity) that works on both database systems to check if the database is up and running?

Comment: why do you need to do such a thing? Surely the database is already running by the time someone is making a request to the application?

Comment: I have a docker-compose with different containers for database and app. And it is not sufficient to make the app "depend_on:" database, since the database init takes some additional time after the operating system is running.

Comment: why not make it depend on the database? You can't do anything useful with the application until it's running, so what's the difference? But anyway, I don't think you actually need to run a query in order to know if the database is up...all you need to do is check that the command to open a connection succeeds.

Answer (score 5):

Yii2 has a property to verify if a connection exists or not, it is really not necessary to create a script for this, since this framework has an abstraction implemented for the databases it supports ([$isActive property](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#$isActive-detail)).

> $isActive public read-only property Whether the DB connection is
>   established
>
> public boolean getIsActive ( )

You can do the check in your `default controller` in the following way:

```
<?php

class DefaultController extends Controller 
{
    public function init()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->db->isActive) {
            // The connection does not exist.
        }

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

It is not good practice to force waiting for a connection to a database unless there are very specific requirements. The availability of a connection to the database must be a mandatory requirement for an application to start and the application should not "wait" for the database to be available.

There are ways to run containers in docker in an orderly manner or with a specific requirement, this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) could give you a better option instead of delegating this to the application.

Comment: `isActive()` is not really reliable in some cases - it does not test if connection is still active, so `isActive()` may return `true` also for disconnected connection.

Comment: The case where `isActive` returns a `true` value is when the database server is restarted while the script is running. Is a [feature](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14359) to consider within the framework that is already working to implemen.

Comment: Connection can be also closed after long inactivity - it is quite common problem for long-running scripts.

Comment: Right, but this case only happens in Yii2 if you first configured the database connection with the parameter `'attributes' => [PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true]`

Comment: It is not true, and `ATTR_PERSISTENT` may be really bad idea if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Again, you are right. My comment regarding the attribute responds to persistent MySQL connections <-> PHP, since by default PDO opens and closes connection in every execution of a script, I am not saying that this attribute should be used for this case, I think we lost the initial idea.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `SELECT 1` which is standard SQL.

You can use [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a8da3e6e3a264e6df27455d1a6fa4cc6) to test against various servers.

The server could go away an any time so checking the error response with every query is a much better approach.